# How to integrate the NativeContacts Functionality for adding a New mobile number into contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have a requirement in which i have to integrate the native contacts functionality of IPhone Device. I have a UITextField where I am entering a new phone number. when i have eneter it completely it should allow me to add that contact to the Native Device contacts. I am able to load the native contacts on clicking abutton but I am unable to get the Add contacts functionality.

Please suggest me/

Thanks
Rizwan

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible With out using AddressBook , AddressBookUI frameworks.
Look in the link mentioned below to do this using these frameworks:

[How to add a contact from my app to the iOS address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334047/how-to-add-a-contact-from-my-app-to-iphone-address-book)