# implicit conversion of objective-c pointer type nsstring to cpointer type 'CFTypeRef'

Tags: iphone, ios, casting

I am using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334047/how-to-add-a-contact-from-my-app-to-iphone-address-book) for storing contact info, in my opinion there is little bit problem with ARC.

when I use this below code it's work fine.

```
ABAddressBookRef libroDirec = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef persona = ABPersonCreate();

ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"JustTESTING", nil);
```

on other hand when i use this below code its gives error  **implicit conversion of objective-c pointer type nsstring to cpointer type 'CFTypeRef'**

```
NSString * prefName = ref.fName; 

ABAddressBookRef libroDirec = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef persona = ABPersonCreate();

ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, prefName, nil);// error in prefName
```

Thanks

Comment: [bridge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7261584/900873)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a cast to make ARC happy:

```
ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)prefName, nil);
```

`prefName` is an `NSString *` and the 3rd parameter needs a `CFTypeRef`.